# I have a problem with my function authentication. I get an empty token while everything works fine when I use postman

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I have a problem with authentication using reactJs in frontend and spring boot and jwt in backend. when I use postman I get the token but when I implement it in reactJs I get an empty token and the following error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljd9Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkUvB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O42U7.png)

this is my log in function :

```
    onLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password};
    courseService.login(user)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            const jwtToken = response.headers.get("token");

            if (jwtToken !== undefined) {
                localStorage.setItem("token", jwtToken);
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }
            else {
                this.setState({open: true});
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

this is courseService :

class CourseService {

```
retrieveAllCourses() {
    return axios.get(COURSE_API_URL+'/courses');
};
getCoursesByThemeId = (id) => {
    return axios.get(COURSE_API_URL+'/themes/'+id+'/courses');
}
getCourse = (id) => {
    return axios.get(COURSE_API_URL+'/courses/'+id);
}
getTheme = (id) => {
    return axios.get(COURSE_API_URL+'/themes/'+id);
}
findInscriptionByCourseId = (courseId)=>{
    return axios.get(INSCRIPTION_API_URL+'/inscription/'+courseId)
}
retrieveAllThemes() {
    return axios.get(COURSE_API_URL+'/themes');
};
editCourse(course) {
    return axios.put(COURSE_API_URL + '/courses/' + course.id, course);
};
addCourse(course) {
    return axios.post(COURSE_API_URL+'/new-course', course);
};
addUser(user){
    return axios.post(USER_API_URL+'/register', user);
}
login(user) {
    return axios.post(USER_API_URL+'/login', user);
};
deleteCourse = (id) => {
    return axios.delete(COURSE_API_URL+'/courses/'+id);
};
addInscription(inscription){
    return axios.post(INSCRIPTION_API_URL+'/inscriptions',inscription);
};
```

}

export default new CourseService();

Comment: Please add the screenshot of console.log(response.headers)

Comment: Hi @Abraoui, Please provide the code for the implementation of `courseService.login` without it it's impossible to know what `response` actually is

Comment: Maybe have a look here how to do things: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/. Search for `Great! We got the token`, token is in the body.